# Upload files into the Storage/Apps directory in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Any ideas on how to upload files directly into the Storage/Apps/My_folder_name directory? I have tried the code below but doesn't seem to work.

```
  {
    if ($request->hasfile('filenames')) {
      foreach ($request->file('filenames') as $file) {
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        Storage::move($file, 'my_folder_name');
      }
      return back()->with('Success!','Data Added!');
    }
  }
```

I can find examples which upload to the public folder however, I would prefer the storage folder in order to restrict access.

Comment: have you tried `$file->store(...)` or `$file->storeAs(...)` ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I used the *putfile* method in the storage class

```
  {
    if ($request->hasfile('filenames')) {
      foreach ($request->file('filenames') as $file) {
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = Storage::putFileAs('Labels', $file, $filename); //This will store in the Storage/Apps/Labels folder...
      }
      return back()->with('Success!','Data Added!');
    }
  }
```

Do not forget to **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;**

Answer (score 0):

Try below simple code for store file:

```
$pathAndName = Storage::disk('local')->putFile('My_folder_name', request('file_name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think you should choose the local storage disk

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('local')->put($file, 'my_folder_name');
```

If you want to view detail config, you can see is file **config/filesystems.php**

You can read detail is https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-local-driver